# Sap UI Core Library Issue in Eclipse Orion WebIDE

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, sap-web-ide, web-ide, eclipse-orion

I would like to run WebIDE by using Eclipse Orion. But I'm getting an error while loading sap.ui.core.js library. I've tried a couple of things be able to resolve this issue. But I couldn't fix it. Where am I doing mistake ? What should I do ?
Here is the screenshot of my faced issues:

[image: SAPWebIDE]

[image: MacOs Application Folder]

Comment: sap.ui.core.js file can not load from this link: http://localhost:9090/webidedispatcher/resources/sap-ui-core.js

Comment: 1) Please paste the error messages in full text, not in screenshot (screenshots cannot be searched). 2) Are you sure that your web server orion is up and running correctly?